# Image and video size massively increased and I can not backup them

Tags: windows-10, video, images, virus

Eventually, I do not know when exactly, I checked my files and found all video and image sizes massively changed (for example, a folder that was 3TB is now 4GB).

I've tried many things, like booting to safe mode, checking folders via cmd, full scanning system after reboot, installing TotalAV antivirus and scanning the system, but nothing changes. I now just want to back up my media and remove Windows.

I should mention that after the size changed, the size on disk is even smaller than the original (for example, a 7.16GB image reports as 4KB on disk).

Comment: I'm afraid it's a corrupted filesystem. It's too late to back those up. Running a disk check should fix existing problems and prevent further corruption (unless your disk is failing), but you won't get those files back.

Comment: @gronostaj I check up disk with windows disk check tool. But nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

To attempt to fix the corruption and recover the files:

1. Reboot to WinRE

   1. Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced startup - Restart now > 
       Troubleshoot > Advanced > Command Prompt
   2. Identify the drive letter for the partition with the corrupted files: 
      `diskpart` > `lis vol` > `exit`
   3. Check for corruption and recover bad sectors *(takes several hours)* 
      `chkdsk c: /x /r /b` *(replace `c:` with drive letter from 1.2)*
2. Use [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and/or [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover your files

   - *Do not save the recovered files to the same drive*
3. Check the drive's [S.M.A.R.T](https://www.z-a-recovery.com/manual/smart.aspx) data to determine if this was caused by a hardware fault:

   1. [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/download/) [Standard Edition] will allow viewing S.M.A.R.T data from Windows

      - I'm not sure if it allows running a S.M.A.R.T test, but if not, see 3.2
   2. Use a Linux LiveUSB to run a long S.M.A.R.T test

      1. Create an [Ubuntu InstallUSB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2-requirements) > boot it > choose Try Ubuntu
      2. Once at the Ubuntu Desktop, open a terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
      3. Intstall `smartmontools` *(at `postfix` prompt, select `no configuration`)*:

         ```bash
         sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install smartmontools
         ```
      4. List attached disks:

         ```bash
         ls /dev/sd*
         ```

         - If unsure which disk *(`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.)*:

           ```bash
           sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>
           ```
      5. Run a long S.M.A.R.T test *(takes several hours)*:

         ```bash
         sudo smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>
         ```

         - To periodically check progress:

           ```bash
           sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | grep progress
           ```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: DSIKPART does not have that DSKCHK command.

Comment: @Mahdi `chkdsk` is not a diskpart command, you should enter it directly in the command prompt.

Comment: @Mahdi Please refer to the `DiskPart` command sequence in 1.2, specifically, the last command (`exit`)

Comment: I did this its finishes with error.

Comment: @Mahdi What ended in error?  _Please be more specific in your replies, else there's no way to help you._  If the S.M.A.R.T test ended in error, the HDD is damaged and must be replaced... If `chkdsk` failed, please provide details.